# PXOverride ProjectEntry - CopyTask / error with field does not exist

Tags: acumatica

I would like to override the function CopyTask to add note field.
When I create the override function

```
public delegate PMTask CopyTaskDelegate(PMTask task, Int32 ProjectID, DefaultFromTemplateSettings settings);
[PXOverride]
public PMTask CopyTask(PMTask task, Int32 ProjectID, DefaultFromTemplateSettings settings, CopyTaskDelegate baseMethod)
{
  PMTask dst = Tasks.Insert(new PMTask { TaskCD = task.TaskCD, ProjectID = ProjectID });
  dst.RateTableID = task.RateTableID ?? Project.Current.RateTableID;
  ...
}
```

I have this error :

```
\App_RuntimeCode\ProjectEntry.cs(80): error CS0103: The name 'Tasks' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Hello, I don't see the Tasks collection defined anywhere in the code! Do you have it defined in your code?

Comment: I am so bad, thanks / The declaration is not in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I had in the same class 2 declarations :

```
public PXSelect<PMTask, Where<PMTask.projectID, Equal<Current<PMProject.contractID>>>> Tasks;
public PXSelect<PMProject, Where<PMProject.baseType, Equal<CTPRType.project>,And<PMProject.nonProject, Equal<False>,And<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>> Project;
```